# To Show restricted links on Homepage based on the username we get from siteminder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, siteminder, security-constraint

We have siteminder authentication and I am able to fetch the screenname(username) from the siteminder.
Now I have to create groups based on the screennames. The groups will be Admin and Others.
If the screenname is under admin group , it will be able to access each and everything else if the screenname is under other group, a different homepage should appear containing only the links which other group can access. 
How do I achieve this?

I have tried to use Realm, user,group roles method but it is prompting for username and password. Also I dont want to use any username and password because I want to filter on the basis of screennames.

PS: I dont have knowledge of spring framework and other framework. I know only JSP and Servlets.

Regards,
Ethan

Comment: If siteminder itself doesn't have the ability to create groups (I have no clue if it does) then you can make a db table associating usernames to groups. It would be a shame though, since then you're managing the username in two places.

Comment: Siteminder have the ability to create groups though we wont be using that. Also db table is not possible to use :(. Any other way please.

Comment: I have found the solution. Got all the information through the header names.